# Toggle Breakpoint in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test()
    Dim g1val As Integer
    g1val = 0

    For i = 3 To 27
        If g1val >= Cells(33, i).Value Then
            g1val = g1val
        ElseIf g1val < Cells(33, i).Value Then
            g1val = Cells(33, i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here when I puts toggle breakpoints in 3rd line and executes by F8, On faster execution 'g1val' doesn't picks up any value.The same happens when I executes the code without any breakpoints. Can u help??....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g1val = Cells(33,i).Value` should be the first line after the For statement.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 reasons why your code might not be working

1. You are not doing a numeric comparison
2. Your Cells object might be referring to the `ActiveSheet` which might not be the sheet that you want. Fully qualify your cells object.
3. Your Row or Column values are incorrect

Also I noticed one more thing. You first `IF` is not required as you are setting the value of `g1val` to `g1val`. You can write the code as

```
Sub Test()
    Dim g1val As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For i = 3 To 27
            If g1val < Val(Trim(.Cells(33, i).Value)) Then _
            g1val = Val(Trim(.Cells(33, i).Value))
        Next i
    End With

    Debug.Print g1val 
End Sub
```